# Implementing Class - REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hello fellow coding friends,

I have a small problem. First of all I am very new to REACT and Typescript otherwise I think it would be no problem to solve this myself. But i need the following code to be implemented as a class (as I otherwise would need to duplicate this code):

```
const CustomFilterComponent = (props): ReactElement => {
const [selectedVal, setSelectedVal] = useState(0);

function handleChange(e): void {
    const val = e.target.value;
    setSelectedVal(val);
    props.onFilterChanged(props.columnDef.tableData.id, val);
}

return (
    <th>
        <Select  value={selectedVal} onChange={handleChange}>
            <MenuItem value={"0"} disabled>
                Filter
            </MenuItem>
            {phpVersions.map((phpVersion): ReactElement => {
                return (
                    <MenuItem value={phpVersion}>{phpVersion}</MenuItem>
                )
            })}
        </Select>
    </th>
);
};
```

I need this to be a class as I am making a filter for php versions in my example. But I also need this for symfony as a reference. This means I would need to change the return property. At the moment i call my method like this:

```
const newColumns = [...this.state.columns];
newColumns[3].filterComponent = CustomFilterComponent;
this.setState({columns: newColumns});
```

I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: so what do you actually need just converting above functional component to the class component?

Comment: Yes. But my knowledge currently is just not enough

Comment: I dropped the basic conversion for you

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simple class component for above functional component:

```js
import React from "react";

interface ColumnDef {
  tableData: {
    id: number
  }
}

interface Props {
  columnDef: ColumnDef
  onFilterChanged: (prev: number, next: number) => void
}

interface State {
  selectedVal: number
}

class CustomFilterComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    selectedVal: 0,
  }
  
  handleChange = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    this.setState(val);
    this.props.onFilterChanged(this.props.columnDef.tableData.id, val);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <th>
        <Select value={this.state.selectedVal} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <MenuItem value={"0"} disabled>
                Filter
            </MenuItem>

            {/* What is phpVersions? */}
            {phpVersions.map((phpVersion): ReactElement => {
              return (
                <MenuItem value={phpVersion}>{phpVersion}</MenuItem>
              )
            })}
        </Select>
      </th>
    );
  }
}
```

Note: I aslo commented what `phpVersions` comes from as well? If that is a part of `props`, just simply change to: `this.props.phpVersions`

Comment: php Version is actually just an array. but it is not defined in props.

Comment: this.props.onFilterChanged(this.props.columnDef.tableData.id, val); - this line is not working for me. I get the following error: "onFilterChanged does not exist on type...".

Comment: Ah I forgot you using Typescript? If so, we have to define props/state to pass to component as typings

Comment: I switched the answer as Typescript style

Comment: BTW I don't know why you put  the logic of rendering `phpVersions` into this component as this property doesn't belong to the component. You might have to check again though.

Comment: Thanks I will look at this in the near future. Just got something else to do